# Getting a navigation property populated when using a parent class to fetch

Tags: entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-5

I am using a membership provider that specifies required fields in user such as username and password. You can then inherit this user class to create your own user with any other fields you need.

I added an account like so

```
public Account AdminAccount { get; set; }
```

when i now get my user using the membershipprovider it does this:

```
return _context.Set<TUser>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
```

The class definition for this membership class looks like so

```
public class FlexMembershipUserStore<TUser> 
    : IFlexUserStore
        where TUser: class, IFlexMembershipUser, new()
```

So I send in my user class when creating it, and the class knows about Tuser as a IFlexMembershipUser.

However IFlexMembershipUser does not have my AdminAccount property, only my class that inherits from IFlexMembershipUser has that.
And so when I fetch my user even tho he in the database has a field called AdminAccount_Id which is set correctly I only get AdminAccount to be null.

I see the problem of course with the membership only seeing IFlexMembershipUser and my property not existing on that class but other scalar values are read in properly.

Is there anything I can do about it.
In this particular case I can make the account keep track of it's admins as a user list instead. So I can solve this that way but I am still curious if this can be solved otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that EF only loads things you tell it to for performance reasons. You have two options for loading the remote nav properties, Eager loading (my prefered) or lazy loading.

With Eager loading you tell EF at query time you are interested in the specific nav property and it will go ahead and load it for you. To do this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

....

_context.Set<TUser>().Include(u=>u.AdminAccount).SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
```

Comment: I was afraid of that you would say exactly that. The problem you see is that the membership provider only deals with it's master class that does not have any navigation properties. It's my subclass that has those. And since the membership provider should not really know about my project I think I have come to the end of the road here. I will simply reverse the logic and put the administrators in Account instead of Account in user.